# sympy lambdify with sympy matrix and numpy vector inputs

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, lambdify

I want to compute a symbolic gradient with sympy, e.g.,

```
import sympy as sym
x, y, z  = sym.symbols("x y z", real=True)

T = sym.cos(x**2+y**2)

gradT = sym.Matrix([sym.diff(T, x), sym.diff(T,y), sym.diff(T,z)])
```

Now I would like to create a lamddify function with this expression:

```
func = lambdify((x,y,z), gradT,'numpy')
```

To use the function I have:

```
gradT_exact = func(np.linspace(0,2,100), np.linspace(0,2,100), np.linspace(0,2,100))
```

and I receive the following error:

```
<lambdifygenerated-3>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return (array([[-2*x*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [-2*y*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [0]]))
```

If I change T to be a function of x,y,z it gives me no problems...
Why is it giving warnings when T only depends on x and y and z is set to zero.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bug in sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21613

Comment: @OscarBenjamin, I don't see how `lambdify` can adjust that `[0]` to accurately reflect possible shape(s) of the other terms (for a `x,y,z` in general).

Comment: In general it is impossible for lambdify to know what the user wants when they substitute symbols for arrays into a matrix-valued expression e.g. where should the extra array dimensions go? It would be possible to define something sensible but it probably needs to be a different function from lambdify that would have arguments for controlling how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The `gradT` expression:

```
In [84]: gradT
Out[84]: 
⎡        ⎛ 2    2⎞⎤
⎢-2⋅x⋅sin⎝x  + y ⎠⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢        ⎛ 2    2⎞⎥
⎢-2⋅y⋅sin⎝x  + y ⎠⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣        0        ⎦
```

and its conversion to `numpy`:

```
In [87]: print(func.__doc__)
Created with lambdify. Signature:

func(x, y, z)

Expression:

Matrix([[-2*x*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [-2*y*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [0]])

Source code:

def _lambdifygenerated(x, y, z):
    return (array([[-2*x*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [-2*y*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [0]]))
```

If `x` and `y` are arrays, then 2 terms will reflect their dimension(s), but the last is `[0]`. That's why you get the `ragged` warning.

`lambdify` does a rather simple lexical translation.  It does not implement any deep understanding of `numpy` arrays.  At some level it's your responsibility to check that the numpy code looks reasonable.

with scalar inputs:

```
In [88]: func(1,2,3)
Out[88]: 
array([[1.91784855],
       [3.8356971 ],
       [0.        ]])
```

but if one input is an array:

```
In [90]: func(np.array([1,2]),2,3)
<lambdifygenerated-1>:2: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return (array([[-2*x*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [-2*y*sin(x**2 + y**2)], [0]]))
Out[90]: 
array([[array([ 1.91784855, -3.95743299])],
       [array([ 3.8356971 , -3.95743299])],
       [0]], dtype=object)
```

The result is object dtype containing 2 arrays, plus that `[0]` list.

To avoid this problem, the `lambdify` would have to produce a function like:

```
In [95]: def f(x,y,z):
    ...:     temp = 0*x*y
    ...:     return np.array([-2*x*np.sin(x**2 + y**2), -2*y*np.sin(x**2 + y**2)
    ...: , temp])
```

where `temp` is designed to give `0` value, but with a shape that reflects the broadcasted operations on `x` and `y` in the other terms.  I think that's asking too much of `lambdify`.

```
In [96]: 

In [96]: f(np.array([1,2]),2,3)
Out[96]: 
array([[ 1.91784855, -3.95743299],
       [ 3.8356971 , -3.95743299],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ]])
```